# At most one connected component of $\{z: |f(z)| < M \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show that if $f$ is an entire function, then there is at most one connected component of the complement of $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ of the set $\{ z: |f(z)| < M \}$.

Based on the post [At most one connected component of unbounded portion of entire function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881451/at-most-one-connected-component-of-unbounded-portion-of-entire-function) taking the complement in $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ rather than $\mathbb{C}$ is necessary. If I can show that all the components of the complement are unbounded, then they all contain $\infty$ and so there is only one component. However, it is true that all the components are unbounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a bounded component of $\{z: |f(z)| \ge M\}$, $f$ would have to attain a maximum.

Comment: But if the maximum occured on the boundary of the component wouldn't this be fine?

Comment: @Mike If $z$ lies on the boundary then $|f(z)|=M$ so $z$ is the maximum on the connected component union $\{z:|f(z)|\geq M\}$.  I guess this makes it a local maximum?

Comment: @tkf This might sound silly, but why does $|f(z)| = M$ on the boundary?

Comment: @Mike By construction any $z$ in the component will satisfy $|f(z)|\geq M$.  If $|f(z)|>M$ then $|f|$ will be greater than $M$ on some open ball in the component contradicting $z$ on the boundary.

Comment: @tkf I agree that $|f|$ is greater than $M$ on some open ball, but how do you know it is contained in the said component. Could it not intersect some other component of the complement of $\{ z: |f(z)| \geq M \}$?

Comment: The open ball is connected and intersects the component, hence its union with the component is connected.  However by definition of connected component, the component cannot be contained in a larger connected set.  Thus the open ball is contained in the component.