# For an non-constant and non-vanishing entire function $f$ , the set $ U = \{ z \in C : | f(z) | <1 \} $ has unbounded connected component.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f$ is an non constant entire function with $ f(z) \neq 0 $ for all $ z \in C $. Then the set $ U = \{ z \in C : | f(z) | <1 \} $ has unbounded connected component.

---

**My attempt**

---

I have concluded some facts:

- $ U $ is an open set;
- $ f(z) \neq 0 $ for all $ z \in C $, then there exists $ \epsilon >0 $ such that $ | f(z) | > \epsilon$;
- Since $f$ is non-vanishing, we can define another entire function g such that $ g(z) = \frac{1}{ f(z) } $.

But I was not able to conclude the result.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747801/at-most-one-connected-component-of-z-fz-m?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

note that assuming $f$ non-constant ($f=2$ has $U$ empty), $g=1/f$ is non-constant and entire hence $g$ is unbounded, so $U$ being given by $|g(z)|>1$ must be unbounded (hence it has at least one unbounded connected component) as $V$ given by $|g(z)| \le 1$ cannot contain the exterior of a disc radius $R$ for all $R$ large enough as that would imply $g$ bounded (as $g$ is bounded inside the closed disc of radius $R$, if it were bounded by $1$ outside, it would be bounded on the plane), while the union of $U$ and $V$ is the plane! Done!